# How to set different rules for different collection of users for accessing same firestore collection?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a collection of data, say, `products` and two different set of users `merchants` and `users`. How do I grant read write access to merchants on `products` and only read access to `users`?

```
match /users/{userId} {
   allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

The above rule only defines access for a single users.

Comment: There's not enough information here to know exactly what you need to do.  First, I suggest reading the documentation about accessing other documents in Firestore, then editing your question to say in more detail what your data actually looks like, and what you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Answer (score 1):

Starting point:

```
match /users/{userId} {
   allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
match /products/{productid} {
   // Anyone authenticated can read
   allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
   // Only merchants can write
   allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.type == 'merchant'
}
```

Assuming users have field `type` with possible values `['user', 'merchant']`

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents)